# What item should I use to keep track of my creature’s Power and Toughness?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I’m a new player to MTG and I was wondering what item I should use to keep track of the Power and Toughness in my creatures. Like if I would enchant one of my creatures with a +1/+1 I would need to be able to show it right? I thought I could use dice but I saw many people online discourage it because it can get knocked down easily and other problems. I don’t know if I should use dice or use something more convenient and better.

Comment: The question that was marked as a duplicate deals exclusively with counters, this question asks about effects that modify P&T in general, specifically mentioning things like enchantments (likely auras) and is not a duplicate.

Comment: If an enchantment changes P/T, the enchantment itself keeps track of the change. Using counters to keep track of an aura effect only creates confusion by potentially counting the effect twice

Comment: I was using the enchantment thing as an example. I am also wondering that if you are going to use dice as counters can you use one for power and one for toughness? Also thanks for clearing up about the enchantment P/T for me. Another question is that since you said that one “enchantment” card is used to keep track in of the P/T, do you like put the enchantment card under the one it’s modifying or something?

Comment: @thatonefriend6 Modern card design only uses +1/+1 and -1/-1 counters, so there is no reason to keep track of power and toughness separately.

Comment: And just in case it wasn't clear: It's customary to only keep track of +1/+1 and -1/-1 counters with physical items placed on cards. The P/T values printed on the card and P/T modifications from other cards on the battlefield are not usually tracked with additional physical items, since those values can already be calculated from cards on the battlefield.